# Theme a Panelized Content Type Not Working

Tags: 7, theming

I'm trying to add a content type to an existing site. I've added it, panelized it, added fields, and everything seems to be working well. There is a second panelized content type in this site that is being themed from a file titled `node--typename.tpl.php` and is working correctly.

I attempted to name mine `node--my-typename.tpl.php`, cleared all caches, but nothing works.

I `drush vset theme_debug 1` and checked for `tpl` suggestions but it doesn't really mention anything pertaining to theming the content type—just panelizer.

Is there a setting I'm missing here? I've combed through both content types and can't see a difference but one allows theming using `node--` files and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong.

In my content type, under Panelizer > Full Page Override > Content I had to add "Rendered Node" to the main content area. This allowed me to use the `node--my-typename.tpl.php` file to theme this panelized content type.